# jQuery.inputmask and its placeholder

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

Here is my code:

```
                        $("input").inputmask("decimal", {
                            "radixPoint": ",",
                            "groupSeparator": " ",
                            "digits": 2,
                            "autoGroup": true,
                            "digitsOptional": true,
                            "suffix": " EUR",
                            "placeholder": "129,5",
                            "clearMaskOnLostFocus": false,
                        })
```

Everything works great but I don't really understand how to display "**129,5**" as a placeholder instead of "**1**"?

Thanks in advance for your help!

I tried to search within StackOverflow and read the official documentation for jQuery.inputmask, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through jQuery.inputmask source codes and understood that there's nothing to do about it so I had to find out different approach.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The docs for the inputmask plugin contain a section on [Setting Initial Values](https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/#/documentation/numeric#setting-initial-values).

It states that you just need to set the `value` attribute of the input.

You could do this in HTML, ex: `<input value="129,5">`

Alternatively, you could do it with jQuery:

```js
$(function () {
  $("input")
    .val("129,5")
    .inputmask("decimal", {
      "radixPoint": ",",
      "groupSeparator": " ",
      "digits": 2,
      "autoGroup": true,
      "digitsOptional": true,
      "suffix": " EUR",
      "clearMaskOnLostFocus": false,
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/inputmask@5.0.8/dist/jquery.inputmask.min.js"></script>
<input>
```